# How can i get value from URL in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

http://localhost:3000/admin/parking/airportParkingPriorityUpdate/**xyz**

How do i get value "***XYZ***" from the url using javascript

Comment: are you looking for angular way of getting url parameters?

Comment: Show us your `router` configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const list = location.href.split('/');
list[list.length-1]
```

Comment: but are you checking for angular way of doing it?

Comment: Now add a query string on your url and see if it still works...

Answer (score 0):

```js
let url = "http://localhost:3000/admin/parking/airportParkingPriorityUpdate/xyz";

let parts = url.split("/");

let final = parts[parts.length - 1];

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `window.location` object gives you everything you need to accomplish this. Check the [API docs for Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) to see all the available values you have regarding the current URL.

For this specific example you have given. `window.location.pathname` will be `/admin/parking/airportParkingPriorityUpdate/xyz`.

You can split this easily with `window.location.pathname.split('/')`. It's then a case of taking the last array value from the result.

```
const path = window.location.pathname;
const parts = path.split('/');
const result = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

**<= IE 10**

Just to note that IE <=10 never includes the leading `/` in `window.location.pathname`.

Comment: You're welcome @karthi but your accepted answer is not going to work all the time. This will.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```js
// create a url - object
let url = new URL('http://localhost:3000/admin/parking/airportParkingPriorityUpdate/xyz');

// use just the pathname of the url (if there would exist url - params in the url they would be filtered out)
let result = url.pathname.match(/((?!\/).)+$/)[0];

// use the result however you want
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also get URL parameters using javaScript. Try below code.

http://localhost/mypage?id=10&name=Simy

**getURLParameter("id") --> Returns 10**

```js
function getURLParameter(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```